# .delay() not working with slideUp()

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, delay, slideup

As the title says, for some reason a box is not delaying before it slides back up. 
Right now if you hover over a div called "#box" with the class of ".boxset", the div "#slidebox" appears. #slidebox also has the class of ".boxset". If you move your mouse away from these two divs, #slidebox will slideUp. In this regard it is working beautifully.

I want there to be a delay before it slides back up, but for some reason delay() is not working.

The critical line of code is in the second of the two functions under hover()

I.E:

```
$('#slidebox').stop().delay(600).slideUp({
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?

Thanks a bunch for any help!

The jQuery

```
$('#slidebox').hide();
$('.boxset').hover(
            function() {  
    $('#slidebox').stop().slideDown(
        {
        duration:600, 
        easing: "swing",
        queue: false,
        complete: function() {
        $('#slidebox').removeAttr('style');}  //End complete   
        } //End object literals
        ); // End slideDown
                    } // End first function
    ,
    function() {
        $('#slidebox').stop().delay(600).slideUp({   
        duration:600, 
        easing: "swing",
        queue: false,
        } // End object literals
                    ); //End slideUp
                    } // End second function   

); // End Hover
```

The HTML

```
<div id="box" class="boxset"></div>
<div id="slidebox" class="boxset"></div>
```

The CSS

```
#box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: orange;
    drop-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: white;
    diplay:block;
    text-align: right;

}

#slidebox { 
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(23,34,1, .1);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case, you want to use a setTimeout.

```
var timeOut;
$('.boxset').hover(
    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        $('#slidebox').stop().slideDown({
            duration:600, 
            easing: "swing",
            queue: false,
            complete: function() {
                $('#slidebox').removeAttr('style');}  //End complete   
        });
    },
    function() {
        $('#slidebox').stop();
        timeOut=setTimeout(function(){
            $('#slidebox').slideUp({  
                duration:600, 
                easing: "swing",
                queue: false,
            });
        }, 600);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HDLCE/1/

Comment: working code but the same problem is happening as described in my above comment. Thanks though!

Comment: That's because the mouseenter doesn't stop the timer. I'll update the code.

Comment: hmm... it's working **perfectly** in jsFiddle... but for some reason it's not working on my local file. I've been checking it for a long time but it's just not working for some reason. With this new code, #slidebox is visible on the load of the page, and hovering does not elicit any response.

I wish I could provide some constructive response but unfortunately I'm not familiar with timers yet.

Comment: If it's doing nothing, there is an error occurring in the javascript. Run it through your debugger. Or copy the code directly from the jsfiddle into your page.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing both. Well after many minutes changing the around code I finally got it to work perfectly on my local file. I'm really not sure what was causing it to not work... The only thing I can say is that the debugger kept alerting the error of "reference error: $  not defined" and the line number was always at the beginning of my code right after <script>. Finally I just wiped out all other code and started fresh. Anyway, thanks a bunch. Wish i understood timer I could appreciate the code.  This is the new best solution because it achieved everything I was originally looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15368/discussion-between-isaac-fife-and-shaltnot)

Answer (score 2):

From the JQuery documentation:

> queue: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the
>   effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of
>   jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case
>   the animation is added to the queue represented by that string.

Try setting queue:true for your handlerOut function on the hover

Change the nesting of the Div elements and remove the "boxset" class from the inner div so that your event handler isn't firing multiple times. That should fix the inconsistent behavior.

```
<div id="box" class="boxset">
<div id="slidebox"></div>
​</div>​
```

Comment: +1, nice one, that seems to work, see DEMO: `http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/KBv7V/`

Comment: Wow, nice. That worked quite well. For some reason I thought I had already tested that solution. Maybe I tried setting it true for the handlerIn. Best answer!

Comment: Hmm. Oddly, though, now #slidebox will slide back up without delay if you move the mouse onto it (from #box --the orange thing). The delay only works if you move your mouse away from #box directly onto white-space above and to the left/right. Going to unaccept this answer for a little bit but will accept it again if no one else comes up w/ a better solution! Thank you though.

Comment: In this case actually, I think the setTimeout is better. delay cannot be stopped. The pause in the queue will always happen, so the mouseenter event will never stop the slideup.

Comment: Yeah. Though I'm still not exactly sure what is going on. What is delay stopped by? Queue? How does queue effect it?